# How to avoid temporary object creation (and deletion) when constructing with initializer list?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have two template classes `A` and `B`:

```
// Non-modifiable template class.
template<class T>
class A{
private:
    T* ptr;
    int size;
public:
    A( int const inputSize ):
        ptr{ new T[ inputSize ] }, size{ inputSize }
    {}
};

// Modifiable template class.
template<class T>
class B{
private:
    A<T> a_obj;
    int idx;
public:
    B( int const inputSize ):
        a_obj{ A<T>{ inputSize } }, idx{ 0 } //temporary object creation?
    {}
};
```

`B` has a member variable with type `A` which needs to be constructed during the construction of `B`. Is there a way to avoid temporary construction of object with type `A` when constructing `B` (if it happens at all)? Also please suppose we cannot modify `A` template class.

What I'm trying to get at is a similar functionality we see with `emplace_back()` compared to `push_back()` in vectors: objects are constructed at the place and not twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can (and should) pass the `A` constructor arguments directly without code implying a temporary, i.e. instead of...

```
a_obj{ A<T>{ inputSize } }, idx{ 0 } //temporary object creation?
```

...use...

```
a_obj{ inputSize }, idx{ 0 }
```

(Whether the former actually creates a temporary is up to the optimiser).

Comment: Thank you. Some times some obvious information in my mind gets blocked and when I realize it, I ask myself "what the hell was I thinking?".

Comment: @Farzad: no worries!  Lots of things look obvious after they're pointed out, but what you coded made a lot of intuitive sense too.  Cheers.